# Python 3: Read text file that is in list format

Tags: string, python-3.x, list

I have one large text file that contains data in the form of a list and its just in one line. See examples

*Text file contents: [{"input": "data1"}, {"input": "data2"}, {"input": "data2"}]*

I am reading this file using python 3 and when I use the read() method, I get one large string however I want to convert this string to a list while maintaining the same format that is in the text file. Is there anyway that this can be achieved? Most of the posts talk about using the split method to achieve this which does not work for this case.

In JavaScript I generally use the stringify and parse methods to do these kinds of conversions but I am not able to find this in python. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide expected output based on sample input?

Comment: ".. I want to convert this string to a list while maintaining the same format that is in the text file". But it *is* a single long string in the text file. What do you have using `split`, and how does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load json from a a file using Python's built-in [json package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('foo.json') as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
... 
>>> print(data)
[{'input': 'data1'}, {'input': 'data2'}, {'input': 'data2'}]
```

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb